# Best way to upload Github's master branch to SFTP

Tags: git, github, sftp, travis-ci, continuous-delivery

What's the best way to enable a pipeline that uploads the GitHub master branch code to an SFTP server? I have (PHP) files on the master branch that need to be synced with an SFTP (production) server.

I have tried Travis CI with [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) however that doesn't work since cURL doesn't support sftp, only ftp.

I've also tried [this guide](http://kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/use-travis-ci-to-update-your-website-using-ftp-and-git.html) but that also uses cURL, which won't work since it doesn't support sftp.

Are there any programs (alternatives to Travis CI) that I can use or should I stick to Travis CI and try something else?

Comment: Why not just use `sftp` program at Travis? You can run it non-interactively: `echo put -r root_dir | sftp -b- user@host:/path`.

Comment: @phd how would I specify the password?

Comment: `sftp` uses `ssh` for transport. Use `ssh` keys for authentication. Or write `put -r root_dir` into a file and run `sftp -b batchfile user@host:/path`.

Comment: What if no ssh keys are available. I just want to use a clear plain text password. @phd

Comment: Use a file to pass the command and stdin to send the password.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can handle this.

First, many versions of `curl` do indeed support SFTP; it's a matter of using an appropriate version. Debian and Ubuntu provide `curl` binaries that can be used to upload using SFTP, either with a username and password or a key.

Second, you can use a program such as `lftp` which is scriptable and can also be used to upload to a remote server using SFTP, either with a username and password or a key. This binary is also available in Debian and Ubuntu.

Third, you can use the `sftp` command line program from OpenSSH. However, since OpenSSH always prompts for username and password on `/dev/tty`, preventing it from being used in a script, you either need to use SSH keys for this purpose or you need to use something like `expect` that can script the interaction with the `sftp` program and provide a TTY to input the data.

If you are doing a build on Travis on Linux and it doesn't provide the proper binaries, you can always do the build in a suitable Docker container instead of on the Travis system itself.

Comment: Hi! `Debian and Ubuntu provide curl binaries that can be used to upload using SFTP, either with a username and password or a key.` that's not the case here. SFTP is not a supported protocol when I'm doing `curl -V`, I've tried `lftp`, thanks for that, that worked.